# Creating a simple audio driver for a Cyclone V SoC (Linux)

Tags: audio, linux-kernel, driver

I'm designing software for a board using an [Altera Cyclone V SoC](https://www.altera.com/products/fpga/cyclone-series/cyclone-v/overview.html) (ARM Cortex-A9 running Linux coupled to an FPGA). The Linux OS is running fine with support for on-board peripherals (Ethernet, SD card, etc.) and I can access the FPGA from userspace programs, currently using mmap(), though.
Now, the board could also be used as an SDR (software defined radio) platform, so as a gimmick I've implemented a very simple FM transmitter. This already works well, but it is only a static configuration inside the FPGA with no real connection to the operating system.

What I would like to do is to link the transmitter to the operating system, ideally so that it can be used as a standard audio output device, i.e. a soundcard. The hardware side is flexible and at the moment very simplistic:

- A status register tells if samples are being played.
- A memory address register holds the current read pointer into the system memory from where the samples are fetched (DMA).
- A register containing the remaining number of samples to play.
- A register to set the hardware sampling rate.

This interface is not fixed, if necessary, it could be changed rather easily. If sensible, I could also update the interface to resemble that of an existing device, so that I could use its driver.

Now the question is, how I should start with the integration into Linux, i.e. how to get/build a suitable kernel module. I'm rather new to kernel module development, so I don't really know where to start. The [documentation of the Linux sound subsystem](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/Documentation/sound/alsa?id=refs/tags/v4.3.3) would certainly contain a lot of useful information, but I'm missing the "big picture", e.g. what should go into which part of the driver, or how the actual interface to the system (ALSA if I got that correctly) has to look like.

btw: I know the LDD3 book and have an idea of how a kernel module should look and work in general, but I don't know how to build one that plays nicely together with the audio subsystem.

Thanks for comments, suggestions, links, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just some pointers, hope it helps.

[Alsa Overview (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture)

[Audio In Embedded Linux Systems(Free Electrons)](http://free-electrons.com/doc/embedded_linux_audio.pdf)

[Writing an Alsa Driver](http://www.alsa-project.org/~tiwai/writing-an-alsa-driver/)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for! Of course I'm still open for other comments and suggestions, but I think I'll get along with what I have now :)

Comment: glad to hear it @PhilippBurch !

Answer (score 0):

With the information found in the [presentation on Free Electrons](http://free-electrons.com/doc/embedded_linux_audio.pdf) and the [ALSA driver tutorial](http://www.alsa-project.org/~tiwai/writing-an-alsa-driver/), both mentioned by @Mali, I finally managed to build my simple driver. I will post the code below, maybe it is of use for someone else. It is directly based on the sound/drivers/dummy.c driver in the Linux kernel sources. One very important thing is to change the buffer preallocation in `snd_card_fmplayer_pcm` from

```c
snd_pcm_lib_preallocate_pages_for_all(pcm,
    SNDRV_DMA_TYPE_CONTINUOUS,
    snd_dma_continuous_data(GFP_KERNEL),
    0, 64*1024);
```

to

```c
snd_pcm_lib_preallocate_pages_for_all(pcm,
    SNDRV_DMA_TYPE_DEV, /* This type is veeery important! */
    NULL,
    MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
```

Without this change, the driver basically works, but the played data hardly resembles the actual samples, which seems to be caused by caching effects.

The module still needs the kernel timer (either a systimer or a high-resolution timer) as in the dummy.c implementation, since the hardware is not configured to generate interrupts while playing. This should be fixed if it is to be used for some serious application.

Bye,
Philipp

```c
/*
 *  ALSA soundcard kernel module to access the fmplayer FPGA core.
 * 
 *  This code is mostly based on the ALSA dummy soundcard in
 *  sound/drivers/dummy.c written by Jaroslav Kysela <p...@p...cz>
 *
 *   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 *   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 *   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
 *   (at your option) any later version.
 *
 *   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 *   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 *   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 *   GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 *   You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 *   along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
 *   Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307 USA
 *
 */

#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/err.h>
#include <linux/platform_device.h>
#include <linux/jiffies.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/time.h>
#include <linux/wait.h>
#include <linux/hrtimer.h>
#include <linux/math64.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <sound/core.h>
#include <sound/control.h>
#include <sound/tlv.h>
#include <sound/pcm.h>
#include <sound/rawmidi.h>
#include <sound/info.h>
#include <sound/initval.h>

#include <linux/io.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <asm/io.h>
#include <linux/dma-mapping.h>

MODULE_AUTHOR("Philipp Burch <p...@h...ch>");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("FM player sound card");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_SUPPORTED_DEVICE("{{ALSA,fmplayer}}");

// FPGA core -------------------------------------------------------------------

// Slave register address map (byte address offsets):
// 0x00  RW STAT_CTRL
//       Bit  0: Set to enable the block. If cleared, the output is forced
//               to all-zeros.
// 0x04  RW MEMSTART
//       Starting address of the sample memory (16-bit aligned). A write
//       to this register resets and disables the player. When read,
//       this register contains the address from where the next
//       sample will be read. It can be used as progress information,
//       so that one half of the memory can be overwritten by new
//       data after it has been played.
// 0x08  RW MEMEND
//       Last address of the sample memory, after which the address
//       counter wraps back to MEMSTART.
// 0x0c  RW SAMPRATE
//       Update value for the sampling rate DDS. This should be
//       selected according to the nominal sampling rate of the
//       data to play.

#define REG_BASE            0xc0003000

#define REGNUM_RW_STAT_CTRL 0
#define REGNUM_RW_MEMSTART  1
#define REGNUM_RW_MEMEND    2
#define REGNUM_RW_SAMPRATE  3

#define REG_SIZE_BYTES      32

#define DDS_CLK_FREQ        100000000
#define DDS_WIDTH           32ULL

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------


#define MAX_PCM_DEVICES     1
#define MAX_PCM_SUBSTREAMS  1
#define MAX_MIDI_DEVICES    0

/* defaults */
#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE     (64*1024)
#define MIN_PERIOD_SIZE     64
#define MAX_PERIOD_SIZE     1024
#define USE_FORMATS         (SNDRV_PCM_FMTBIT_S16_LE)
#define USE_RATE            (SNDRV_PCM_RATE_CONTINUOUS | SNDRV_PCM_RATE_8000_48000)
#define USE_RATE_MIN        1000
#define USE_RATE_MAX        192000
#define USE_CHANNELS_MIN    2
#define USE_CHANNELS_MAX    2
#define USE_PERIODS_MIN     2
#define USE_PERIODS_MAX     1024

static int index[SNDRV_CARDS] = SNDRV_DEFAULT_IDX;  /* Index 0-MAX */
static char *id[SNDRV_CARDS] = SNDRV_DEFAULT_STR; /* ID for this card */
static bool enable[SNDRV_CARDS] = {1, [1 ... (SNDRV_CARDS - 1)] = 0};
#ifdef CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS
static bool hrtimer = 1;
#endif

module_param_array(index, int, NULL, 0444);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(index, "Index value for fmplayer.");
module_param_array(id, charp, NULL, 0444);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(id, "ID string for fmplayer.");
module_param_array(enable, bool, NULL, 0444);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(enable, "Enable this fmplayer.");
#ifdef CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS
module_param(hrtimer, bool, 0644);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(hrtimer, "Use hrtimer as the timer source.");
#endif

static struct platform_device *devices[SNDRV_CARDS];


struct fmplayer_timer_ops {
    int (*create)(struct snd_pcm_substream *);
    void (*free)(struct snd_pcm_substream *);
    int (*prepare)(struct snd_pcm_substream *);
    int (*start)(struct snd_pcm_substream *);
    int (*stop)(struct snd_pcm_substream *);
    snd_pcm_uframes_t (*pointer)(struct snd_pcm_substream *);
};


struct snd_fmplayer {
    struct snd_card *card;
    struct fmplayer_model *model;
    struct snd_pcm *pcm;
    struct snd_pcm_hardware pcm_hw;
    spinlock_t mixer_lock;
    u32 *iomem;
    struct snd_kcontrol *cd_volume_ctl;
    struct snd_kcontrol *cd_switch_ctl;
    const struct fmplayer_timer_ops *timer_ops;
};

/*
 * system timer interface
 */

struct fmplayer_systimer_pcm {
    spinlock_t lock;
    struct timer_list timer;
    unsigned long base_time;
    unsigned int frac_pos;  /* fractional sample position (based HZ) */
    unsigned int frac_period_rest;
    unsigned int frac_buffer_size;  /* buffer_size * HZ */
    unsigned int frac_period_size;  /* period_size * HZ */
    unsigned int rate;
    int elapsed;
    struct snd_pcm_substream *substream;
};

static void fmplayer_systimer_rearm(struct fmplayer_systimer_pcm *dpcm)
{
    mod_timer(&dpcm->timer, jiffies +
        (dpcm->frac_period_rest + dpcm->rate - 1) / dpcm->rate);
}

static void fmplayer_systimer_update(struct fmplayer_systimer_pcm *dpcm)
{
    unsigned long delta;

    delta = jiffies - dpcm->base_time;
    if (!delta)
        return;
    dpcm->base_time += delta;
    delta *= dpcm->rate;
    dpcm->frac_pos += delta;
    while (dpcm->frac_pos >= dpcm->frac_buffer_size)
        dpcm->frac_pos -= dpcm->frac_buffer_size;
    while (dpcm->frac_period_rest <= delta) {
        dpcm->elapsed++;
        dpcm->frac_period_rest += dpcm->frac_period_size;
    }
    dpcm->frac_period_rest -= delta;
}

static int fmplayer_systimer_start(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream)
{
    struct fmplayer_systimer_pcm *dpcm = substream->runtime->private_data;
    spin_lock(&dpcm->lock);
    dpcm->base_time = jiffies;
    fmplayer_systimer_rearm(dpcm);
    spin_unlock(&dpcm->lock);
    return 0;
}

static int fmplayer_systimer_stop(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream)
{
    struct fmplayer_systimer_pcm *dpcm = substream->runtime->private_data;
    spin_lock(&dpcm->lock);
    del_timer(&dpcm->timer);
    spin_unlock(&dpcm->lock);
    return 0;
}

static int fmplayer_systimer_prepare(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream)
{
    struct snd_pcm_runtime *runtime = substream->runtime;
    struct fmplayer_systimer_pcm *dpcm = runtime->private_data;

    dpcm->frac_pos = 0;
    dpcm->rate = runtime->rate;
    dpcm->frac_buffer_size = runtime->buffer_size * HZ;
    dpcm->frac_period_size = runtime->period_size * HZ;
    dpcm->frac_period_rest = dpcm->frac_period_size;
    dpcm->elapsed = 0;

    return 0;
}

static void fmplayer_systimer_callback(unsigned long data)
{
    struct fmplayer_systimer_pcm *dpcm = (struct fmplayer_systimer_pcm *)data;
    unsigned long flags;
    int elapsed = 0;

    spin_lock_irqsave(&dpcm->lock, flags);
    fmplayer_systimer_update(dpcm);
    fmplayer_systimer_rearm(dpcm);
    elapsed = dpcm->elapsed;
    dpcm->elapsed = 0;
    spin_unlock_irqrestore(&dpcm->lock, flags);
    if (elapsed)
        snd_pcm_period_elapsed(dpcm->substream);
}

static snd_pcm_uframes_t
fmplayer_systimer_pointer(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream)
{
    struct fmplayer_systimer_pcm *dpcm = substream->runtime->private_data;
    snd_pcm_uframes_t pos;

    spin_lock(&dpcm->lock);
    fmplayer_systimer_update(dpcm);
    pos = dpcm->frac_pos / HZ;
    spin_unlock(&dpcm->lock);
    return pos;
}

static int fmplayer_systimer_create(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream)
{
    struct fmplayer_systimer_pcm *dpcm;

    dpcm = kzalloc(sizeof(*dpcm), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!dpcm)
        return -ENOMEM;
    substream->runtime->private_data = dpcm;
    setup_timer(&dpcm->timer, fmplayer_systimer_callback,
            (unsigned long) dpcm);
    spin_lock_init(&dpcm->lock);
    dpcm->substream = substream;
    return 0;
}

static void fmplayer_systimer_free(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream)
{
    kfree(substream->runtime->private_data);
}

static struct fmplayer_timer_ops fmplayer_systimer_ops = {
    .create = fmplayer_systimer_create,
    .free =   fmplayer_systimer_free,
    .prepare =  fmplayer_systimer_prepare,
    .start =  fmplayer_systimer_start,
    .stop =   fmplayer_systimer_stop,
    .pointer =  fmplayer_systimer_pointer,
};

#ifdef CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS
/*
 * hrtimer interface
 */

struct fmplayer_hrtimer_pcm {
    ktime_t base_time;
    ktime_t period_time;
    atomic_t running;
    struct hrtimer timer;
    struct tasklet_struct tasklet;
    struct snd_pcm_substream *substream;
};

static void fmplayer_hrtimer_pcm_elapsed(unsigned long priv)
{
    struct fmplayer_hrtimer_pcm *dpcm = (struct fmplayer_hrtimer_pcm *)priv;
    if (atomic_read(&dpcm->running))
        snd_pcm_period_elapsed(dpcm->substream);
}

static enum hrtimer_restart fmplayer_hrtimer_callback(struct hrtimer *timer)
{
    struct fmplayer_hrtimer_pcm *dpcm;

    dpcm = container_of(timer, struct fmplayer_hrtimer_pcm, timer);
    if (!atomic_read(&dpcm->running))
        return HRTIMER_NORESTART;
    tasklet_schedule(&dpcm->tasklet);
    hrtimer_forward_now(timer, dpcm->period_time);
    return HRTIMER_RESTART;
}

static int fmplayer_hrtimer_start(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream)
{
    struct fmplayer_hrtimer_pcm *dpcm = substream->runtime->private_data;

    dpcm->base_time = hrtimer_cb_get_time(&dpcm->timer);
    hrtimer_start(&dpcm->timer, dpcm->period_time, HRTIMER_MODE_REL);
    atomic_set(&dpcm->running, 1);
    return 0;
}

static int fmplayer_hrtimer_stop(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream)
{
    struct fmplayer_hrtimer_pcm *dpcm = substream->runtime->private_data;

    atomic_set(&dpcm->running, 0);
    hrtimer_cancel(&dpcm->timer);
    return 0;
}

static inline void fmplayer_hrtimer_sync(struct fmplayer_hrtimer_pcm *dpcm)
{
    tasklet_kill(&dpcm->tasklet);
}

static snd_pcm_uframes_t
fmplayer_hrtimer_pointer(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream)
{
    struct snd_pcm_runtime *runtime = substream->runtime;
    struct fmplayer_hrtimer_pcm *dpcm = runtime->private_data;
    u64 delta;
    u32 pos;

    delta = ktime_us_delta(hrtimer_cb_get_time(&dpcm->timer),
                         dpcm->base_time);
    delta = div_u64(delta * runtime->rate + 999999, 1000000);
    div_u64_rem(delta, runtime->buffer_size, &pos);
    return pos;
}

static int fmplayer_hrtimer_prepare(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream)
{
    struct snd_pcm_runtime *runtime = substream->runtime;
    struct fmplayer_hrtimer_pcm *dpcm = runtime->private_data;
    unsigned int period, rate;
    long sec;
    unsigned long nsecs;

    fmplayer_hrtimer_sync(dpcm);
    period = runtime->period_size;
    rate = runtime->rate;
    sec = period / rate;
    period %= rate;
    nsecs = div_u64((u64)period * 1000000000UL + rate - 1, rate);
    dpcm->period_time = ktime_set(sec, nsecs);

    return 0;
}

static int fmplayer_hrtimer_create(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream)
{
    struct fmplayer_hrtimer_pcm *dpcm;

    dpcm = kzalloc(sizeof(*dpcm), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!dpcm)
        return -ENOMEM;
    substream->runtime->private_data = dpcm;
    hrtimer_init(&dpcm->timer, CLOCK_MONOTONIC, HRTIMER_MODE_REL);
    dpcm->timer.function = fmplayer_hrtimer_callback;
    dpcm->substream = substream;
    atomic_set(&dpcm->running, 0);
    tasklet_init(&dpcm->tasklet, fmplayer_hrtimer_pcm_elapsed,
                 (unsigned long)dpcm);
    return 0;
}

static void fmplayer_hrtimer_free(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream)
{
    struct fmplayer_hrtimer_pcm *dpcm = substream->runtime->private_data;
    fmplayer_hrtimer_sync(dpcm);
    kfree(dpcm);
}

static struct fmplayer_timer_ops fmplayer_hrtimer_ops = {
    .create = fmplayer_hrtimer_create,
    .free =   fmplayer_hrtimer_free,
    .prepare =  fmplayer_hrtimer_prepare,
    .start =  fmplayer_hrtimer_start,
    .stop =   fmplayer_hrtimer_stop,
    .pointer =  fmplayer_hrtimer_pointer,
};

#endif /* CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS */

/*
 * PCM interface
 */

static int fmplayer_pcm_trigger(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream, int cmd)
{
    struct snd_fmplayer *fmplayer = snd_pcm_substream_chip(substream);

    switch (cmd) {
    case SNDRV_PCM_TRIGGER_START:
    case SNDRV_PCM_TRIGGER_RESUME:
        iowrite32(1, &(fmplayer->iomem[REGNUM_RW_STAT_CTRL]));
        return fmplayer->timer_ops->start(substream);
    case SNDRV_PCM_TRIGGER_STOP:
    case SNDRV_PCM_TRIGGER_SUSPEND:
        iowrite32(0, &(fmplayer->iomem[REGNUM_RW_STAT_CTRL]));
        return fmplayer->timer_ops->stop(substream);
    }
    return -EINVAL;
}

static int fmplayer_pcm_prepare(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream)
{
    struct snd_fmplayer *fmplayer = snd_pcm_substream_chip(substream);
    struct snd_pcm_runtime *runtime = substream->runtime;
    u64 extrate = (u64)(runtime->rate) << DDS_WIDTH;
    u32 dds_val = (u32)div_u64(extrate, (u64)(DDS_CLK_FREQ));
    u32 dma_startaddr = runtime->dma_addr;
    u32 dma_endaddr = dma_startaddr + (runtime->buffer_size-1)*4;

    /* Configure the sample rate. */
    iowrite32(dds_val, &(fmplayer->iomem[REGNUM_RW_SAMPRATE]));

    /* Configure the DMA addresses. */
    iowrite32(dma_startaddr, &(fmplayer->iomem[REGNUM_RW_MEMSTART]));
    iowrite32(dma_endaddr,   &(fmplayer->iomem[REGNUM_RW_MEMEND]));

    printk(KERN_DEBUG "DMA range: 0x%08x .. 0x%08x\n", dma_startaddr, dma_endaddr);
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "DMA size: %d bytes\n", runtime->dma_bytes);
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "Buffer size: %d frames\n", (int)runtime->buffer_size);
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "Using %d periods of %d frames\n",
        runtime->periods, (int)runtime->period_size);
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "Rate: %d Hz\n", runtime->rate);
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "Channels: %d\n", runtime->channels);
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "%d bits/sample, %d bits/frame\n",
        runtime->sample_bits, runtime->frame_bits);
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "Access: %d\n", runtime->access);
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "Format: %d\n", runtime->format);
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "Subformat: 0x%08x\n", runtime->subformat);

    return fmplayer->timer_ops->prepare(substream);
}

static snd_pcm_uframes_t fmplayer_pcm_pointer(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream)
{
    struct snd_fmplayer *fmplayer = snd_pcm_substream_chip(substream);
    u32 dma_startaddr = substream->runtime->dma_addr;
    u32 dma_curraddr = ioread32(&(fmplayer->iomem[REGNUM_RW_MEMSTART]));

    return (dma_curraddr - dma_startaddr) / 4;
}

static struct snd_pcm_hardware fmplayer_pcm_hardware = {
    .info =            (SNDRV_PCM_INFO_MMAP |
                        SNDRV_PCM_INFO_INTERLEAVED |
                        SNDRV_PCM_INFO_MMAP_VALID),
    .formats =          USE_FORMATS,
    .rates =            USE_RATE,
    .rate_min =         USE_RATE_MIN,
    .rate_max =         USE_RATE_MAX,
    .channels_min =     USE_CHANNELS_MIN,
    .channels_max =     USE_CHANNELS_MAX,
    .buffer_bytes_max = MAX_BUFFER_SIZE,
    .period_bytes_min = MIN_PERIOD_SIZE,
    .period_bytes_max = MAX_PERIOD_SIZE,
    .periods_min =      USE_PERIODS_MIN,
    .periods_max =      USE_PERIODS_MAX,
    .fifo_size =        0,
};

static int fmplayer_pcm_hw_params(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream,
                         struct snd_pcm_hw_params *hw_params)
{
    return snd_pcm_lib_malloc_pages(substream, params_buffer_bytes(hw_params));
}

static int fmplayer_pcm_hw_free(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream)
{
    struct snd_fmplayer *fmplayer = snd_pcm_substream_chip(substream);
    /* Make sure that no more memory is accessed by the DMA. */
    iowrite32(0, &(fmplayer->iomem[REGNUM_RW_STAT_CTRL]));

    return snd_pcm_lib_free_pages(substream);
}

static int fmplayer_pcm_open(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream)
{
    struct snd_fmplayer *fmplayer = snd_pcm_substream_chip(substream);
    struct snd_pcm_runtime *runtime = substream->runtime;
    int err;

    fmplayer->timer_ops = &fmplayer_systimer_ops;
#ifdef CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS
    if (hrtimer)
        fmplayer->timer_ops = &fmplayer_hrtimer_ops;
#endif

    err = fmplayer->timer_ops->create(substream);
    if (err < 0)
        return err;

    runtime->hw = fmplayer->pcm_hw;
    return 0;
}

static int fmplayer_pcm_close(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream)
{
    struct snd_fmplayer *fmplayer = snd_pcm_substream_chip(substream);
    fmplayer->timer_ops->free(substream);
    return 0;
}

static struct snd_pcm_ops fmplayer_pcm_ops = {
    .open =   fmplayer_pcm_open,
    .close =  fmplayer_pcm_close,
    .ioctl =  snd_pcm_lib_ioctl,
    .hw_params =  fmplayer_pcm_hw_params,
    .hw_free =  fmplayer_pcm_hw_free,
    .prepare =  fmplayer_pcm_prepare,
    .trigger =  fmplayer_pcm_trigger,
    .pointer =  fmplayer_pcm_pointer,
};

static int snd_card_fmplayer_pcm(struct snd_fmplayer *fmplayer, int device,
                        int substreams)
{
    struct snd_pcm *pcm;
    int err;

    err = snd_pcm_new(fmplayer->card, "FM player PCM", device,
                         substreams, substreams, &pcm);
    if (err < 0)
        return err;
    fmplayer->pcm = pcm;
    snd_pcm_set_ops(pcm, SNDRV_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, &fmplayer_pcm_ops);
    snd_pcm_set_ops(pcm, SNDRV_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE, NULL);
    pcm->private_data = fmplayer;
    pcm->info_flags = 0;
    strcpy(pcm->name, "FM player PCM");
    snd_pcm_lib_preallocate_pages_for_all(pcm,
        SNDRV_DMA_TYPE_DEV, /* This type is veeery important! */
        NULL,
        MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
    return 0;
}


static int snd_fmplayer_probe(struct platform_device *devptr)
{
    struct snd_card *card;
    struct snd_fmplayer *fmplayer;
    struct resource *res;
    int err;
    int dev = devptr->id;

    err = snd_card_new(&devptr->dev, index[dev], id[dev], THIS_MODULE,
                 sizeof(struct snd_fmplayer), &card);
    if (err < 0)
        return err;
    fmplayer = card->private_data;
    fmplayer->card = card;

    /* Allocate and remap I/O memory for hardware (FPGA) connection. */
    res = request_mem_region(REG_BASE, REG_SIZE_BYTES, "fmplayer");
    if (res == NULL) {
        snd_card_free(card);
        return -ENOMEM;
    }
    fmplayer->iomem = ioremap(REG_BASE, REG_SIZE_BYTES);
    if (fmplayer->iomem == NULL) {
        release_mem_region(REG_BASE, REG_SIZE_BYTES);
        snd_card_free(card);
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    err = snd_card_fmplayer_pcm(fmplayer, 0, 1);
    if (err < 0)
        goto __nodev;

    fmplayer->pcm_hw = fmplayer_pcm_hardware;

    strcpy(card->driver, "fmplayer");
    strcpy(card->shortname, "fmplayer");
    sprintf(card->longname, "fmplayer %i", dev + 1);

    err = snd_card_register(card);
    if (err == 0) {
        platform_set_drvdata(devptr, card);
        return 0;
    }
__nodev:
    snd_card_free(card);
    return err;
}

static int snd_fmplayer_remove(struct platform_device *devptr)
{
    /* Release and unmap the I/O memory. */
    struct snd_card *card = platform_get_drvdata(devptr);
    if (card != NULL) {
        struct snd_fmplayer *fmplayer = card->private_data;
        if (fmplayer != NULL) {
            /* Make sure that the driver is stopped. */
            iowrite32(0, &(fmplayer->iomem[REGNUM_RW_STAT_CTRL]));
            iounmap(fmplayer->iomem);
            release_mem_region(REG_BASE, REG_SIZE_BYTES);
        }
    }
    snd_card_free(platform_get_drvdata(devptr));
    return 0;
}

#define SND_FMPLAYER_DRIVER  "snd_fmplayer"

static struct platform_driver snd_fmplayer_driver = {
    .probe    = snd_fmplayer_probe,
    .remove   = snd_fmplayer_remove,
    .driver   = {
        .name = SND_FMPLAYER_DRIVER,
        .pm = NULL,
    },
};

static void snd_fmplayer_unregister_all(void)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(devices); ++i)
        platform_device_unregister(devices[i]);
    platform_driver_unregister(&snd_fmplayer_driver);
}

static int __init alsa_card_fmplayer_init(void)
{
    int i, cards, err;

    err = platform_driver_register(&snd_fmplayer_driver);
    if (err < 0)
        return err;

    cards = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < SNDRV_CARDS; i++) {
        struct platform_device *device;
        if (! enable[i])
            continue;
        device = platform_device_register_simple(SND_FMPLAYER_DRIVER,
                             i, NULL, 0);
        if (IS_ERR(device))
            continue;
        if (!platform_get_drvdata(device)) {
            platform_device_unregister(device);
            continue;
        }
        devices[i] = device;
        cards++;
    }
    if (!cards) {
#ifdef MODULE
        printk(KERN_ERR "FM player soundcard not found or device busy\n");
#endif
        snd_fmplayer_unregister_all();
        return -ENODEV;
    }

    return 0;
}

static void __exit alsa_card_fmplayer_exit(void)
{
    snd_fmplayer_unregister_all();
}

module_init(alsa_card_fmplayer_init)
module_exit(alsa_card_fmplayer_exit)
```